# Parsing and formatting JSON date variable

Tags: json, jquery

I am parsing a JSON object with JavaScript and displaying it in a styled HTML table.

The date variable comes as a long string. (e.g. `2011-11-23 10:21:49.695805`)

How can I format the date so as to be displayed: `year-month-day, hour-minute` instead of  `2011-11-23 10:21`?

The AJAX call:

```
$$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/myfolder',
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(json) {
        $$('#JsonGrid').append(CreateTableView(json, "jsonFeed", true)).fadeIn();  
        parseDate();
    }     
});

function parseDate() {

}
```

The json object:

```
[{"status": "success", "date": "2011-11-23 10:21:49.695805", "user": "xy", "jobname": "jobnamexyz"}]
```

Comment: You need to use a date parsing/formatting library, like http://www.datejs.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use date functions, [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/), etc., but if the format is fixed as in your example you can just take the first sixteen characters:

```
var date = json["date"].substr(0,16);
```

EDIT: sorry, just noticed you wanted a comma in there. So:

```
var date = json["date"].substr(0,10) + ", " + json["date"].substr(11,5);
```

EDIT 2: OK, try moving the call to `parseDate()` to *before* you call `CreateTableView()`, so you can "fix" the data before it is used. The following assumes the `json` is an array of objects:

```
success: function(json) {
    parseDate(json);
    $$('#JsonGrid').append(CreateTableView(json, "jsonFeed", true)).fadeIn();


function parseDate(data) {
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
        if (data[i]["date"])
            data[i]["date"] = data[i]["date"].substr(0,10)
                            + ", " + data[i]["date"].substr(11,5);
}
```

Comment: here I get: json.date is undefined

Comment: Surely you can take the `substr()` idea from my answer and slot it into your own code? I just noticed your sample JSON is an array with one item in it, so you could say `json[0]["date"].substr(...`, but presumably the real data may have more rows. Your placeholder `parseDate()` function as shown in the question is sitting on its own after you've appended whatever the return from `CreateTableView()` is to your document. I have no idea what that function does, but wouldn't you want to parse the dates inside that function? Or update the JSON before passing it to that function?

Comment: CreateTableView function creates a standard table with column/rows, Parameter Information, objArray like JSON results. here is the code specification: http://www.zachhunter.com/2010/04/json-objects-to-html-table/.. i guess there it would be better to do the time formatting before appending what is returned. I am just now sure how

Comment: I get  data[i].date is undefined
 data[i]["date"] = data[i]["date"].substr(0,10)

Comment: I've updated my answer one more time to allow for items in that json array that don't have a date, but as far as I can see my updated code matches the sample data from your question. Your sample has an array with only one item in it (i.e., only one row in your table) so it's hard for me to see what the problem is - you'll have to figure out the rest.

Comment: it works thank you so much for your help and efforts! cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
$$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/myfolder',
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(json) {
        $$('#JsonGrid').append(CreateTableView(json, "jsonFeed", true)).fadeIn();  
        parseDate(json);
    }     
});


  function parseDate(json) {

        var arr = json["date"].split(/:/);
        var date = arr[0] + ":"+arr[1];
        alert(date);

        return date;

    }
```

Comment: I get:   date is undefined
var arr = date.split(/:/, json.date);

Comment: sorry, it was my fault i updated it, i pasted the old script, but now it is ok. working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.match](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) method to parse the parts of string like "2011-11-23 10:21:49.695805". For example the code

```
var regexp = "([0-9]{4})(-([0-9]{2})(-([0-9]{2})" +
             "([T| ]([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(:([0-9]{2})(\.([0-9]+))?)?" +
             "(Z|(([-+])([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})))?)?)?)?";
var dateString = "2011-11-23 10:21:49.695805";
var d = dateString.match(new RegExp(regexp));
```

will initialize `d` as array where `d[1]`, `d[3]`, `d[5]`, `d[7]`, `d[8]` and `d[10]` are year (2011), month (11), day (23), hour (10), minutes (21), seconds (49). The `d[12]` will be `695805` and only the first tree digits of it are milliseconds. So you can either create a `Date` like

```
var date = new Date(d[1],d[3],d[5],d[7],d[8],d[10],d[12].substr(0,3));
```

or display the parsed date as another string in any other format which you prefer.

Comment: Doesn't `var d = dateString.split(/[ :.-]/);` do the same thing as your regex?

Comment: @nnnnnn: The regex, which I use, verify additionally the input. Look at the constructs `[0-9]` for example.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this jQuery extension can help you out: http://momentjs.com/

Like:

```
var now = moment();
var formatted = now.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY');
```